# I need some help on an XQuery sequence merge that preserves order

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am working on a function to merge a set of sequences that will preserve the order of all of the sequences as best as possible.  Doing a distinct-values($sequences) on all of the sequences does not preserve the order.

I have the following MarkLogic XQuery code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:map-sequence($map, $list as xs:string*) {
    let $count := fn:count($list) - 1
    return for $idx in (1 to $count)
                  return if (map:contains($map, $list[$idx]))
                  then map:put($map, $list[$idx], fn:distinct-values((map:get($map, $list[$idx]), $list[$idx + 1])))
                  else map:put($map, $list[$idx], $list[$idx + 1])
};

declare function local:first($map) {
let $all-children := for $key in map:keys($map) return map:get($map, $key)

return distinct-values(map:keys($map)[not(.=$all-children)])
};

declare function local:next($map, $key as xs:string) {
    if (map:contains($map, $key))
    then if (fn:count(map:get($map, $key)) eq 1)
         then map:get($map, $key)
         else 
            let $children := map:get($map, $key)
            return 
                for $next in $children
                let $others := $children[fn:not(.=$next)]
                let $descedents := local:descendents($map, $next)
              return if ($descedents[.=$others])
                     then $next
                     else ()
    else ()
};

declare function local:descendents($map, $key as xs:string) {
    for $child in map:get($map, $key)
    return ($child, local:descendents($map, $child))
};

declare function local:sequence($map, $key as xs:string) {
    let $next := local:next($map, $key)
    return if (fn:count($next) gt 1)
           then 
                    for $choice in $next
                    return $choice

           else if (fn:count($next) eq 1)
                then ($next, local:sequence($map, $next))
                else ()
};

let $map := map:map()
let $seq1 := local:map-sequence($map, ('fred', 'barney', 'pebbles'))
let $seq2 := local:map-sequence($map, ('fred', 'wilma', 'betty', 'pebbles'))
let $seq3 := local:map-sequence($map, ('barney', 'wilma', 'betty'))

let $first := local:first($map)

return ($map,
for $top in $first
       return ($top, local:sequence($map, $top))
 )
```

it returns

```
{"barney":["pebbles", "wilma"], "fred":["barney", "wilma"], "wilma":"betty", "betty":"pebbles"}
fred
barney
wilma
betty
pebbles
```

It still needs work.  If you add:

```
let $seq4 := local:map-sequence($map, ('fred', 'bambam'))
```

bambam does not show up.  I am still working on it, but if others have suggestions, then I would like to hear them.

Thanks,
Loren

Comment: For your seq1.. seq4 please provide the desired final output. You ask to preserve the sequence yet your example output clobbered the duplicates. Therefore I find it difficult to understand if you actually want all items returned or returned in order  - but skip any item previously provided...

Comment: either fred, bambam, barney, wilma, betty, pebbles or fred, barney, bambam, wilma, betty, pebbles

Comment: I am working on an XSD generator where there would be an xs:choice with barney and bambam as the choices.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your problem, each sequence represents a hierarchy of values, so from the sequence `("foo", "bar", "baz")` we can follow that `"foo" < "bar"`, `"foo" < "baz"` and `"bar" < "baz"` should preferably hold in the resulting ordering.

From your expected output it seems that you want the values to be sorted from the one with the smallest number of (transitive) predecessors (`"fred"` in your case) to that with the most ones (`"pebbles"` with four predecessors: `("barney", "fred", "betty", "wilma")`).

I do not have access to *MarkLogic* and its proprietary maps, so I'll use standard *XQuery 3.0* maps instead. The underlying algorithms should be easy to translate.

As a first step we build a map of all immediate predecessors of each unique value found in at least one of the input sequences. Because XQuery 3.0 maps cannot be modified in-place, we use [`fn:fold-left(...)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-fold-left) to build one up incrementally. Note also that even the first element of each list is added to the map with an empty sequence of predecessors.

```
declare function local:add-preds($map0, $list as xs:string*) {
  fn:fold-left(
    1 to fn:count($list),
    $map0,
    function($map, $idx) {
      map:put(
        $map,
        $list[$idx],
        (: add the current predecessor to the list :)
        fn:distinct-values((map:get($map, $list[$idx]), $list[$idx - 1]))
      )
    }
  )
};
```

Next we need the *transitive closure* of this map of predecessors, so we need to gather all values that can be reached from a given key by a chain of predecessors. We can do this using a simple *depth-first search*:

```
declare function local:transitive($preds) {
  map:merge(
    for $key in map:keys($preds)
    return map:entry($key, local:all-predecessors($preds, $key, $key)[not(. = $key)])
  )
};

declare function local:all-predecessors($succ, $key, $seen0) {
  fold-left(
    map:get($succ, $key),
    $seen0,
    function($seen, $next) {
      if($next = $seen) then $seen
      else local:all-predecessors($succ, $next, ($seen, $next))
    }
  )
};
```

This transforms your example initial predecessor map

```
map {
  "bambam": "fred",
  "pebbles": ("barney", "betty"),
  "fred": (),
  "wilma": ("fred", "barney"),
  "barney": "fred",
  "betty": "wilma"
}
```

and transforms it into

```
map {
  "bambam": "fred",
  "pebbles": ("barney", "fred", "betty", "wilma"),
  "fred": (),
  "wilma": ("fred", "barney"),
  "barney": "fred",
  "betty": ("wilma", "fred", "barney")
}
```

With that map your sorting now becomes very easy: Just take all keys in the map, order them by the number of their predecessors, and output them:

```
let $map0  := map{}
let $map1  := local:add-preds($map0, ('fred', 'barney', 'pebbles'))
let $map2  := local:add-preds($map1, ('fred', 'wilma', 'betty', 'pebbles'))
let $map3  := local:add-preds($map2, ('barney', 'wilma', 'betty'))
let $map4  := local:add-preds($map3, ('fred', 'bambam'))
let $trans := local:transitive($map4)

for $key in map:keys($trans)
order by count(map:get($trans, $key))
return $key
```

This returns your desired result: `"fred", "bambam", "barney", "wilma", "betty", "pebbles"`